# How to read the new line between multi-valued enumerate that has been turned into a string using ""

Tags: ibm-doors

I have an enumerate-type multi-valued attribute in the module in which I am working.

The appearance is as follows:

```
// as it appears in the attribute column
val1
vals-2
vals3
// below is what is written in my script to turn the contents this attribute 
// into a string (for this particular object)
string ovp = o."AttribName" // I have assigned it to a string in this manner
```

If I print the string, it prints out in a column format, like it appears in the attribute column.  How has the new line been defined in this string?

I would like to use the new line definition to put each of the enumerate values into a string array (*string arr[size],* for clarity as I may not be using the right terms).

I am sure there is a way, but I am only two weeks into using DXL, and am at a loss on how to do this, or if there would be another way to do it that might be easier.
I have searched as much as I am able with the keywords that I know.

Thanks in advance for any help or direction.  I will keep trying in the mean-time and see what I come up with. I assume that if I find an answer, I can update this question with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is probably a better way to do this, by querying the attribute definition and then using the 'isMember' function- but this way will return a string array, which you requested.

```
Object o = current

string s = o."Test Enum" ""

int x = 0
int y = 0
int size = 0

if ( s != "" ) {
    size++
}
for ( x = 0 ; x < length ( s ) ; x++ ) {
    if ( s [ x ] == '\n' ) {
        size++  
    }

}
string arr[size]
size = 0
for ( x = 0 ; x < length ( s ) ; x++ ) {
    if ( s [ x ] == '\n' ) {
        arr[ size ] = s [ y : x - 1 ]
        y = x + 1
        size++
    }
}
arr[ size ] = s [ y : ]
```

Of note- this first checks the size of the array, then defines it. Multiple selected attributes have a '\n' as a delimiter, but the last entry won't have that.

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't realise that the boolean check for the newline was '\n' and not "\n".  Only thing I've done differently is that I assign each read string to a temporary string, and use the if(s[i] == '\n') to increment the location in the array.  But the difference, I think is that I have pre-declared my array size, because all of the arrays would end up being size 5 or less.  Saves me an extra for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

A way that I found works for letters is using Regexp.  First, I also want to note that I pre-declare my string arrays as having a size of 10, I can probably decrease this to 5, because the sets of values never seem to go above 4 at most.  That is beside the point, this is what I found worked for my letters.

```
string ovs = o.vs "", ovp = o.vp "", tempstr = ""
Regexp alphabet = regexp"[a-zA-Z]"
int pp, i = 0

for (pp = 0; pp <= length(ovs); pp++) {
    if(alphabet ovs[pp]"")
            tempstr = tempstr "" ovs[pp] ""
    else {
            vsstrarr[i] = tempstr "";
            i++; tempstr = ""
    }
}
```

This does work, but I do not know if multiple Regexp variables would be needed to capture non-alphabet, non '\n' characters.

This was the solution I came up with in the interim, but I accept Balthos' answer as superior.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Version to retrieve all values as part of a layout dxl:

```
Skip allEnumValues(AttrDef ad) {
  AttrType at = ad.type

  Skip elements = create
  int i

  for(i = 0; i < at.size; i++) {
    put(elements, i, (string at.strings[i]))
  }

  return elements;
}

Skip getSelectedValues(Object o, string attr, Skip allPossibleValues) {
  Skip selectedValues = create

  int i = 0
  string str
  for str in allPossibleValues do {
    if(isMember(o.attr, str))
      put(selectedValues, i++, str)
  }

  return selectedValues
}

void x(Module m, Object o) {
  string attribute = "HAD_ComponentsASW"
  Skip allValues = allEnumValues(find(m, attribute))
  Skip selectedValues = getSelectedValues(o, attribute, allValues)

  string str
  for str in selectedValues do
    display(str ",")

  delete selectedValues
  delete allValues
}

Module m = current Module
Object o = obj
x(m, o)
```